# com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaper import is Erroring

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, libgdx

When i import this

```
libgdx class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaper
```

I get the following error:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaper is not visible.
```

What causes and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you own that class? Check the visibility modifier (private, public, protected, default) of it

Comment: @Claudio  Yes that attribute is public.

Comment: Where are you trying to import this class? It is only available in projects that depend on the android backend. Thus, you can only import that in your android project.